# Getting JSON formatted response with oracledb npm and nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, oracle, typescript

I'm requesting data using oracledb npm trying to get a JSON formatted response

here is an example of select block I'm using :

```
 const block =
      'BEGIN ' +
      ':response := PK.getData(:param);' +
      'END;';
```

Called using :

```
 const result = await connection.execute(block, bindVars);
```

Then later using express :

```
res.status(200).send(result);
```

In this configuration I get a response with the good data BUT postman tells me that it is a string when it should see it as JSON

```
{ "metadata":[{"client":"name"...
```

If I use .json() :

```
res.status(200).json(result);
```

I get this kind of response with double quotes and escaped chars :

```
"{ \"metadata\":[{\"client\":\"name\"...
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Try: `res.status(200).send(JSON.parse(result));` or `res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(result));`

Comment: With `.send(JSON.parse(` I get the same result as the first and with `.json(JSON.parse(` I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `JSON.parse` on your response, because you can send only `string` as response from server

**Edit:**

Add `Content-Type: application/json` header so it will be auto parsed in Postman

```
res.header('Content-Type' , 'application/json');
```

Comment: .json() on the response does JSON.parse, it's from express

Comment: Do `JSON.parse` on client side

Comment: Resolved, there was a special character in the data that blocked JSON.parse(). Your response is the good one :)